# How to create different Themes on top of Valo in Vaadin?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

Now vaadin 7.3 has came out and it has the very nice [Valo Theme](https://vaadin.com/valo) . But I don't know how to import it to my project? Now I am using a default theme with my custom scss files. I would like to taste **Valo** . Please somebody help me how to import valo theme to my project.

More over, how can I choose theme styles? [Valo Theme Demo](http://demo.vaadin.com/valo-theme/) has different theme styles such as *Default, Blueprint, Dark, Metro, Flat*. How to choose this categories as I wish?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

read the fine manual: https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/themes.valo.html#themes.valo.use

there is a whole section dedicated to Valo

the different themes on top of Valo as seen in the [valo-demo](http://demo.vaadin.com/valo-theme/#!common) are all done with the setting of the main SASS variables seen in the book.

e.g. https://github.com/vaadin/valo-demo/blob/master/src/main/webapp/VAADIN/themes/tests-valo-flatdark/_variables.scss

Answer (score 9):

Further to the accepted answer, you can specify the theme using the `@Theme` annotation on your UI class and extend the theme by creating a folder with the name of your theme under `VAADIN\themes`.

Inside that folder you'd create a styles.scss and .scss:

styles.scss

```
@import "licensing.scss";

.licensing {
  @include licensing;
}
```

licensing.scss

```
@import "../valo/valo.scss";

@mixin licensing {
  @include valo;
}
```

Theme annotation: [Example on github](https://github.com/manicmonkey/licensing/blob/master/Licensing-UI-Vaadin/src/main/scala/com/magmanics/licensing/ui/LicensingUI.scala#L40).

Theme files: [Example theme folder](https://github.com/manicmonkey/licensing/tree/master/Licensing-UI-Vaadin/src/main/webapp/VAADIN/themes/licensing).