# Using custom CSS theme in vaadin

Tags: vaadin

I want to change the line size for a label.

```
Where do I put the CSS file?
What do I write in it?
What is the syntax to import it?
How do I call it in my class?
```

Thank you.

Comment: The book of vaadin has a very good section about this. https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/themes.html

Answer (score 1):

There are a few articles here covering this topic:

- how to manage themes in general https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/themes.html
- how to create and manage own theme https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/themes.creating.html
- how to use Valo theme https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/themes.valo.html
- blog post "Using VAADIN Themes Effectively" https://www.vodori.com/blog/using-vaadin-themes-effectively/
- more on this topic [How to create different Themes on top of Valo in Vaadin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25720113/how-to-create-different-themes-on-top-of-valo-in-vaadin)